# Scheduling Emails with Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, scheduled-tasks, django-celery

I want to schedule emails using Django. Example ---> I want to send registered users their shopping cart information everyday at 5:00 P.M.

How would I do this using Django? I have read a lot of articles on this problem but none of them have a clear and definite solution. I don't want to implement a workaround.

Whats the proper way of implementing this? Can this be done within my Django project or do I have to use some third-party service?

If possible, please share some code. Otherwise, details on how I can implement this will do.

Answer (score 2):

There's no built-in way to do what you're asking.  What you could do, though, is write a management command that sends the emails off and then have a crontab entry that calls that command at 5PM (this assumes your users are in the same timezone as your server).

Another alternative is using celery and celery-beat to create scheduled tasks, but that would require more work to set up.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a background worker like `celery` or `redis-queue` for the background tasks.

Celery: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html

Redis Queue: https://python-rq.org/docs/

Also there is one really simple package that use database as the broker
https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/